# Does save() method works of update in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have **Message** model class. I want to check weather particular entry exist in DB table. If it doesn't exist then save new entry in DB table and if it exists then update current entry.

Now the problem is when entry exists (update) in the DB table, Save() method gives exception.
'CHttpException' with message 'Your request is invalid.'

Can i use save() method instead of update() method for updating records?

```
     $message = Message::model()->find($criteriaMessage);       
     if (!isset($message)){
        $message = new Message();
        $message->id = $tagMessage->id;
        $message->language = $language;
        $message->translation = $translation;    
     }
     else
        $message->translation = $translation;

     if(!$message->save()){
        return false;
     }
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Save method will call update.

Comment: save() method first validates the model... and then depending whether the record is new it calls insert() or update()

Answer (score 0):

you could just do:

```
$message = Message::model()->find($criteriaMessage);
$message->your_field = $someValue;
$message->save();
```